# C# Regex to match a directory pattern

Tags: c#, regex

I would like a regex to run against Directory.GetAllDirectories()
e.g.

```
 Directory.GetDirectories(pathToMonitor, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
.Where(path => new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).IsMatch(path))
.ToList();
```

The directories follow a pattern like this:

> [Variable number of directories]\$PROJECT$\$TYPE$\$BRANCH$\[Variable
>   number of directories]

I would like to ignore the first set of [Variable number of directories], followed by exactly 3 directories. I do not want to include directories that have anything after the $BRANCH$ directory. The $TYPE$ directory must be "Ft" or "Dev".

I have the following pattern which almost works...

```
string pattern = @"\w+\\(Ft|Dev)\\";
```

Unfortunately that pattern will grab all folders after the $BRANCH$ folder as well.

Concretely, a list of folders like this:

- C:\Users\Me\Desktop\Project\Dev\Branch\
- C:\Users\Me\Desktop\Project\Dev\Branch\sub\sub
- C:\Users\Me\Desktop\Project\Ft\Branch\sub\sub
- C:\Users\Me\Desktop\Project\Ft\Branch\
- C:\Users\Me\Desktop\Project\Qa\Branch\
- C:\Users\Me\Desktop\Project\Qa\Branch\sub\sub

Should be filtered down to this after the regex:

- C:\Users\Me\Desktop\Project\Dev\Branch
- C:\Users\Me\Desktop\Project\Ft\Branch

EDIT: Cleaned up formatting on directory pattern

Comment: add '^' at the end of your regex : @"\w+\\(Ft|Dev)\\Branch\\^"

Comment: 0 matches when I do that.

Comment: '$' sorry ... i mix up '$' and '^'. One means the beginning and the other the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with this pattern:

```
@"\w\\(?:Ft|Dev)\\Branch\\?$"
```

Where `$` is an anchor for the end of the string.